# Unexpected behaviour of string.replace() in Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I discovered today that the function `string.replace(str1, str2)` in Python 3 as well as Python 2 does not behave in the way I instinctively thought it would:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> str = ' not not not not Cannot not not not '.replace(' not ', ' NOT ')
>>> str
' NOT not NOT not Cannot NOT not NOT '
```

I understand why this happens: apparantly the `replace` function, once it finds a match, goes on on the first character after the previous found match which happens to be `n` in my case. Hence the second (and fourth...) `not` is never recognized, as the leading space is missing.

What is the standard way to replace strings to avoid the counter-intuitive behaviour above (so that all `␣not␣`s are capitalized)?

I understand that I can split my string into takens, change the `not`s to `NOT`s and recombine it, but that is not what I am looking for. I suspect there is a proper replacement way available in Python.

Comment: Why you are not using `str = ' not not not not Cannot not not not '.replace('not', 'NOT')`?

Comment: Can't you just do ` str = ' not not not not Cannot not not not '.replace(' not', ' NOT')`? Replacing <space>NOT<space> with <space>NOT

Comment: Yes, `str.replace` is non-overlapping. Why not use a regex with word boundaries, and `re.sub`?

Comment: @Ahsanul Haque: I cannot do that cause then `Cannot` changes to `CanNOT`

Comment: `>>> str = ' not not not not Cannot not not not '.replace(' not', ' NOT')
>>> str
' NOT NOT NOT NOT Cannot NOT NOT NOT '`

Comment: @roymustang86: This would work in this example, but fail for example for `not nothing` as `nothing` would be changed as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import re

s = re.sub(r"\bnot\b", "NOT", s)
```

Use a regular expression to match word boundaries rather than trying to match the spaces in between words.